# Unity: Map Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") in iOS touch

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I can use `Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")` to get obtain the key <kbd>Space</kbd> by default. How can I map screen touch to the "Jump" action in iOS?

In this [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html), it explains only obtaining touches in JavaScript. While in this [video tutorial](http://youtu.be/xuX2T5vSMOo), it only mentions about Button. Is there a way to directly map screen touch/ gesture to a pre-defined action (like Jump) ?

*Note: I use mono C# script.*

Comment: Why not simply create a button and hook it up to that? Otherwise you'd have to work with Input.touches/Input.GetTouch and map a specific region.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to demonstrate a basic understanding of programming, but your rep suggests that we're not on the same page. Can you clarify? Try reading all of the documentation for the members of the Input class with "Touch" in their name, first.

Comment: @Bart the user interface of the game I currently work on does not involve buttons. In fact, transparent buttons cannot be applied in the current project too.

Comment: @Jessy wait. Documentation does not mention about mapping mobile actions to default inputs (like "Jump" action) in Input Manager. If you have experience in Unity, you'll know what I'm talking about. Input Manager accepts only Mouse, Keyboard & Joystick as input.

Comment: The Input Manager hasn't been updated since pre-2005; it does not deal with Touch structs. How would that even make sense, though, to say that every touch event is a "Jump"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are more than one way to get Touch evens in unity:

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
    //Your stuff here
}
```

The above demonstrates using [Input.GetTouch](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html%E2%80%8E)

However, there's an alternative, which I tend to prefer:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    //Your stuff here
}
```

or

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    //Your stuff here
}
```

The above use [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) and [Input.GetMouseButtonUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) respectively, which not only trigger on the left mouse click, but also trigger on touch events for iOS and Android. As suggested by the names, `GetMouseButtonDown` triggers when you first touch the screen and `GetMouseButtonUp` triggers when your finger releases. You'll obviously want to add some extra checks in there, for example to make sure the user isn't trying to drag something, or if he's keeping his finger pressed on the screen etc.

However keep in mind that the above will trigger no matter where you click, so long as the script containing them is active. So if your game has buttons as well (which I'm guessing it will), you could either check if the click/touch is in a certain region, or you could add a transparent plane in front of the camera and behind your buttons, then check for clicks like this:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject.name == "myObjectName")
    {
        //Your stuff here
    }
}
```

The above will only trigger if you left click over a gameObject with a name you choose (which also has a collider) and there's nothing else between it and the camera. A transparent plane will catch all your clicks, allowing you to stick other elements above it.

If I haven't explained something well enough, or you have any other questions, lemme know and I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: Before using `GetTouch(0)`, should we check how many touches exist, e.g. something like `if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.TouchBegan)`?

Comment: On the other hand, can we natively map it in Unity's Input Manager?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor right yeah, forgot about the touchcount bit. I'm not sure you can map Touch to the jump, but you can probably map the left mouse button to it, which as mentioned in the answer, doubles as touch on smartphones.

Comment: @Steven Mills .name is a property of UnityEngine.Object, not just GameObject.

Comment: @Jessy I suppose `hit.collider.name` would give the same name, but I I just feel more at ease seeing a gameObject somewhere in there. You could even compare the actual GameObject if there's a reference to it, but names are probably easier.

Comment: I don't think names are ever easy, unless you never define the strings in code. Uniy isn't going to update your code when a Game Object name changes unless you make an Editor script that alters your text files. Still, I think it's fine for this example. And maybe what you're doing with .name is good practice; Unity might change it to be more meaningful down the road, and any code without .gameObject.name could break, if you changed a Component name in an existing project.